# circular divs computed width incorrect causing not to be circular

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I have some circle divs (using large border-radius) and they're different sizes on different screen sizes using media queries. However the width doesn't kick in correctly on some media query sizes. For example here is a screenshot of it is extra small devices:

[image]

The images shows that the width and height are set to 80px in css however the computed width is 63px.

When I drag the screen wider, I am seeing the circles gradually become wider and wider until they are circles, kind of like a "responsive" div, rather than a div that only changes size at certain width breakpoints.

Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/15513/

How can I get the circle divs to always be circles (same width as height)?

html:

css:

```
#about-page {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 57px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    min-height: 480px;
    justify-content: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
#content-container {
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 200;
    }
}
.circle-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 75px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-flex;
}
/* xs */

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    .circle {
        height: 80px;
        width: 80px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
}
/* s */

@media only screen and (min-width: 544px) {
    .circle {
        height: 110px;
        width: 110px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
}
/* m */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .circle {
        height: 120px;
        width: 120px;
        margin: 8px;
    }
}
/* L */

@media(min-width:992px) {
    .circle {
        height: 130px;
        width: 130px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
}
/* xl */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .circle {
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: They shrink because they no longer fit in the available space of the flex-container. You either add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the container, or make the "circles" smaller in that media query if you want all of them in the same row. Use `flex-shrink: 0;` in your `.circle` class to see what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using flexbox (specifically `inline-flex`) so by default, the circles will shrink to fit the container element. To prevent this, set `flex-shrink: 0` or `flex: 0 0 auto;` to prevent this behaviour.

```
.circle {
  border-radius: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/15520/